# Highchart changes chart width when user hides the graph lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, legend

I have so many lines displayed in [**my graph**](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/extras/arctic_sea_ice_graph.php), that I wanted to add a function to turn them off, and turn only selected ones on. That's why I have a "Show Legend", "Show All" and "Hide All" button alongside my graph:

[image]

Now, a strange thing happens, when I click directly on the button "Hide All" (usually I click on "Show Legend" first, and then on "Hide All" - then, everything is as expected): the graph lines disappear (good), but the graph get's extended to the right, visible by the extended X-axis line (bad):

[image]

If I "Show All" lines again, the graph looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me out on this? I tried to fix the graph width in the "chart" settings, but that's clearly ignored. What else can that be?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Have you tried to set the [showEmpty](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.showEmpty) flag on a xAxis ?

Comment: Tried it, but didn't change anything. The logic behind what is happening seems to me be the following: The graph has a certain width. A space is "reserved" for the legend. And somehow, by using jQuery to hide the lines, it occupies suddenly the whole space... Strange behaviour, bug...

Comment: Is there anyway to set the graph within the "HideAll"-function to the correct graph-width? Something like `$('#hideAll').on('click', function(){ chart.update{width: '900'}; .... }`

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo on the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I've tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/u9pjbu6k/1/). But the buttons are not yet working... Not sure why, guess it's a thing with the "function(chart)"? Sorry, I am rather dumb concerning this... To be seen if this works with these dummy data, or if I need to insert the whole thing (inclusive design)...

Comment: I don't see this is a good experience for the user. Why not have a default where the most "important" or useful line in your series is shown upon first view, or is visible when users want to remove the clutter? Also, you could create an event where a user clicks a line, and all other series are removed. I can work up a fiddle for that second option, if that's something you're interested in viewing. Just let me know!

Comment: @brightmatrix: That sounds like an interesting approach. However, I still think that the use of a legend is useful and necessary, as a user can then more easily select a specific year, or display a certain set of years, which is much more difficult to achieve by selecting the single year in the graph itself.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of an idea you could try. Indeed, if you remove all series from a graph like this, the behavior you observed with the x-axis labels and right side disappearing is expected. What about this approach:

Have one "dummy" series with zeroes for all of its values. Make it white or otherwise invisible (but not hidden, meaning don't set `visible: false`), and use the `showInLegend: false` and `enableMouseTracking: false` only on that series so the user doesn't get a chance to interact with it. When you trigger your buttons to hide all of the series, add a condition to ignore (or restore) only the "dummy" series.

This way, your bundle of lines are removed for the user, but the presence of the "dummy" series tells the graph to keep the axis labels.

Comment: Good idea. I just went with the "average" line being forced to stay, while all others are being turned off. However, it still generates the same problem. It seems to be to be really linked to the legend being turned on and off - and the space of that legend at the right side of the graph being suddenly "available" for the chart itself. When clicking 1) Show Legend (actually, one has to click twice to see the legend, no idea why), 2) Hide All, 3) Hide Legend, 4) Show All ==> it does that... [Here the test case](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/extras/arctic_sea_ice_graph.php).

Comment: Here's what I worked out: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/dbuzmyvr/. In this fiddle, rather than hiding the legend (which causes the chart to reflow into the space where the legend used to be), I instead set the y value of the legend to -1000 to push it off the plot area. Because you can't dynamically set the y value of the legend, I'm drawing a new chart with each instance. However, I set the animation to false so the user shouldn't notice the difference. Let me know if this helps!